# Is there a way to ignore min version for dependency on ios and check it in runtime?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter application and have included an NFC reader, but the problem is that this NFC reader has a minimum requirement of iOS 13, and my application needs to support lower versions. I know in android you can include this line

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="im.nfc.flutter_nfc_kit"/>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml and then at runtime check if you should use that package or not. The problem is that I can't find any similar options for iOS.

Is it the case that iOS does not support overriding the minimum version and let you deal with it at runtime?

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "flutter_nfc_kit":   In Podfile:
> flutter_nfc_kit (from .symlinks/plugins/flutter_nfc_kit/ios)
>
> Specs satisfying the flutter_nfc_kit (from
> .symlinks/plugins/flutter_nfc_kit/ios`) dependency were found, but
> they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

It depends - if you want to send an APDU you need iOS 13+.
If you want just to read a NDEF Tag, then I would use another NFC plugin